# Adding C++ files to compile and run using Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I'm really new to Qt creator and actually I think my very short experience with it didn't go so well.

**Anyways, my question is:**

I used to write C++ programs using Code::Blocks IDE, now I'm trying to make some simple GUI to my program. So that's really why I used Qt creator in the first place.

I have multiple C++ files (.cpp) and (.h) how can I use them into Qt and integrate both "Qt user interface" with my C++ files.
I tried to google about it but got nothing. If anyone can help me how to start, or point out some good tutorial.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info and http://doc.qt.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostly need to write a Qt project file (with some `.pro` extension) for [Qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) (perhaps using `qmake -project`), then use `qmake` to generate a [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), then use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) to build your program.

[Qtcreator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/) is an IDE which might help you, but if you want to use some other editor or IDE, you can run the commands mentioned above appropriately. Actually, once you have generated *once* your `Makefile`, it might be auto-regenerated appropriately when needed. So configuring your IDE to use `make` is probably enough.